# Python / SQLAlchemy format DateRange object

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am using the `DateRange` column type to save reservations for a booking system.
My DB is PosgreSQL and I use Python 3 with Flask and SQLAlchemy.

Even though it should be best practice to use `DateRange`, I dont even find a documentation or anything helpful on how to work with these types.

The SQLAlchemy documentation has only 2 sentences written that such a column type exists.

*A side note here:
All resources, which I find only show that people usually use a start date and an end date. Is my approach with the `DateRange` bad?*

I am currently successfully saving some date ranges into the DB. Now I need to pass all unavailable dates into the view in JSON format, so my custom calendar can use these days to block them. So I need to construct a fitting format. As `datetime` is not serializable I need to convert it to string.

My date range objects look like this atm.:

```
for bdate in room.RoomObject_addresses_UserBooksRoom:
    print (bdate.booked_date)
```

Output:

```
DateRange(datetime.date(2018, 8, 1), datetime.date(2018, 8, 9), '[)')
DateRange(datetime.date(2018, 8, 1), datetime.date(2018, 8, 10), '[)')
DateRange(datetime.date(2018, 9, 7), datetime.date(2018, 9, 14), '[)')
```

I would like to convert them into lists or tuples with this format `%Y-%m-%d`, so I would get this output:

```
['2018-08-01','2018-08-09']
```

I know how it is done with `datetime` objects but here I have no idea, and as mentioned above I was not able to find more information on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy documentation hints that the range types are a Psycopg feature, so looking at [their documentation for the objects in question](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#range-data-types) you will find that `Range` objects have attributes `lower` and `upper` that hold the bounds. With them it is straightforward to produce a list of tuples:

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
bookings = [(format(bdate.lower, fmt), format(bdate.upper, fmt))
            for bdate in room.RoomObject_addresses_UserBooksRoom]
```