# Python postgreSQL sqlalchemy query a DATERANGE column

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, date-range

I have a booking system and I save the booked daterange in a DATERANGE column:

```
booked_date = Column(DATERANGE(), nullable=False)
```

I already know that I can access the actual dates with `booked_date.lower` or `booked_date.upper`

For example I do this here:

```
for bdate in room.RoomObject_addresses_UserBooksRoom: 
    unaviable_ranges['ranges'].append([str(bdate.booked_date.lower),\
    str(bdate.booked_date.upper)])
```

Now I need to filter my bookings by a given daterange. For example I want to see all bookings between 01.01.2018 and 10.01.2018.

Usually its simple, because dates can be compared like this: `date <= other date`

But if I do it with the DATERANGE:

```
the_daterange_lower = datetime.strptime(the_daterange[0], '%d.%m.%Y')
the_daterange_upper = datetime.strptime(the_daterange[1], '%d.%m.%Y')

bookings = UserBooks.query.filter(UserBooks.booked_date.lower >= the_daterange_lower,\
UserBooks.booked_date.upper <= the_daterange_upper).all()
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with UserBooks.booked_date has an attribute 'lower'
```

**EDIT**

I found a [sheet](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-range.html) with useful range operators and it looks like there are better options to do what I want to do, but for this I need somehow to create a `range variable`, but python cant do this. So I am still confused.

In my database my daterange column entries look like this:

```
[2018-11-26,2018-11-28)
```

**EDIT**

I am trying to use native SQL and not sqlalchemy, but I dont understand how to create a daterange object.

```
bookings = db_session.execute('SELECT * FROM usersbookrooms WHERE booked_date && [' + str(the_daterange_lower) + ',' + str(the_daterange_upper) + ')')
```

Comment: [Remember that the actual range objects in Python are a psycopg2 feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036566/python-sqlalchemy-format-daterange-object), so if you need to produce such for use as values in queries, read their docs. Also if using SQLAlchemy instead of raw SQL, check their range operator support: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ranges.RangeOperators

Comment: I know this. The question you linked to is also my question. Maybe I missed something, so I will reread everything. But I think .lower and .upper should work in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query

```
the_daterange_lower = datetime.strptime(the_daterange[0], '%d.%m.%Y')
the_daterange_upper = datetime.strptime(the_daterange[1], '%d.%m.%Y')

bookings = UserBooks.query.\
    filter(UserBooks.booked_date.lower >= the_daterange_lower,
           UserBooks.booked_date.upper <= the_daterange_upper).\
    all()
```

could be implemented using "range is contained by" operator `<@`. In order to pass the right operand you have to create an instance of [`psycopg2.extras.DateRange`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.DateRange), which represents a Postgresql `daterange` value in Python:

```
the_daterange_lower = datetime.strptime(the_daterange[0], '%d.%m.%Y').date()
the_daterange_upper = datetime.strptime(the_daterange[1], '%d.%m.%Y').date()

the_daterange = DateRange(the_dateranger_lower, the_daterange_upper)

bookings = UserBooks.query.\
    filter(UserBooks.booked_date.contained_by(the_daterange)).\
    all()
```

Note that the attributes `lower` and `upper` are part of the  [`psycopg2.extras.Range`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.Range) types. The SQLAlchemy range column types do not provide such, as your error states.

---

If you want to use raw SQL and pass date ranges, you can use the same `DateRange` objects to pass values as well:

```
bookings = db_session.execute(
    'SELECT * FROM usersbookrooms WHERE booked_date && %s',
    (DateRange(the_daterange_lower, the_daterange_upper),))
```

You can also [build literals manually](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-IO), if you want to:

```
bookings = db_session.execute(
    'SELECT * FROM usersbookrooms WHERE booked_date && %s::daterange',
    (f'[{the_daterange_lower}, {the_daterange_upper})',))
```

The trick is to build the literal in Python and pass it as a single value – using placeholders, as always. It should avoid any SQL injection possibilities; only thing that can happen is that the literal has invalid syntax for a `daterange`. Alternatively you can pass the bounds to a [range constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT):

```
bookings = db_session.execute(
    'SELECT * FROM usersbookrooms WHERE booked_date && daterange(%s, %s)',
    (the_daterange_lower, the_daterange_upper))
```

All in all it is easier to just use the Psycopg2 `Range` types and let them handle the details.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the `DateRange`. I am still having issues, but I think I can move forward now. I have an issue with timezones, because I get: `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) function daterange(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, unknown) does not exist
LINE 3: WHERE usersbookrooms.booked_date <@ daterange('2019-01-14T00...
                                            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: Ah true, unsurprisingly `datetime.strptime` produces `datetime` objects, not `date` objects. Added the call to `date()` in order to match the types.

Comment: Dont this and it works now. `un_daterange = DateRange(the_daterange_lower.date(), the_daterange_upper.date())`. Thanks a lot, you helped me a lot a few times already.